# Drawing a directed graph in Maple

Tags: graph-theory, maple, semigroups, cayley-graphs

I have been playing around with some Maple today for a semigroup/ graph theory style project.
I want to draw a left cayley graph with vertices $\{1,....,12\}$ and edges $[5, 5]$, $\{[6, 2].[7, 1], [1, 3], [1, 5], [2, 4], [2, 6], [3, 5], [3, 7], [4, 5], [4, 8], [6, 9], [7, 5], [8, 5], [8, 10], [9, 5], [9, 11], [10, 4], [10, 5], [11, 5], [11, 12], [12, 5], [12, 9]\}$

This is a directed graph; e.g. $[6, 2]$ means I want $6\rightarrow2$ as an edge.

I tried the command:

`S := Graph([5, 5], {[6, 2].[7, 1], [1, 3], [1, 5], [2, 4], [2, 6], [3, 5], [3, 7], [4, 5], [4, 8], [6, 9], [7, 5], [8, 5], [8, 10], [9, 5], [9, 11], [10, 4], [10, 5], [11, 5], [11, 12], [12, 5], [12, 9]})`

However, I get the error message:

"Error, (in GraphTheory:-Graph) vertices must have distinct labels
"

How can I fix this? If someone could give me a code that would produce this graph, I would be forever grateful.

Thank you

Grant

**EDIT:
So the problem was resolved; it was a period between the first 2 edges, silly me. However, I now have a second question: Is there a way it can be set up that Maple gives me the "neatest" looking layout of the vertices to make the graph look the most appealing? For example, with the code above it just lays out 1 to 12 in a circle and looks pretty messy.**

Comment: By [5,5] do you mean a loop on vertex 5? Maple does not handle graphs with loops.

Comment: Ahh ok, right so ignoring the loop (I can deal with that by hand)would the rest of the code be ok?

Comment: Maybe you want to try out SAGE, it is an open source mathematical software. It provides very simple commands to generate and manipulate (directed) graphs (with loops and multiedges) and is a great tool. Check it out on: sagemath.org  (It entirely replaced my usage of maple.)

Comment: You have a period separating the first two edges. If you change that to a comma, then the rest of the code will work.

Comment: Thank you Carl, another quick question.. is there a way it can be set up that maple gives me the "neatest" looking layout of the vertices to make the graph look the most appealing, for example with the code above it just lays out 1 to 12 in a circle and looks pretty messy

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, remove the loop edge and correct the period that should be a comma. Then construct the graph **S** with your **GraphTheory:-Graph** command. Then issue the command

**GraphTheory:-DrawGraph(S, style= spring, redraw, dimension= 3);**

Then click on the graph. Enlarge it by stretching the bounding box in *both* directions. Right click on the plot. Go to the Manipulator submenu. Select Rotate. Now use your mouse to rotate the plot into the best view. You should be able to clearly see three tetrehedra that share a single vertex, 5. There are only two other vertices, 2 and 6, and they are on a path connecting vertices 4 and 9.

If you can't see all that, issue the **DrawGraph** command again: There is a small amount of randomness in the **spring** algorithm, and you may get a better plot.